# Is sound affected by wind force?

Tags: sound

Suppose wind direction is from point **A** to point **B** and some sound source like glass shattering is at point **B**, will sound waves going to point **A** be affected by that wind coming in opposite direction, or will the sound waves cut right through?

Comment: Can you define "affected"? Also, have you tried having a conversation in a storm?

Comment: By affected i meant any additional impact of air force on sound waves going in opposite direction of it. Other than the scalar negation by storm loudness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> will sound waves going to point A be affected by that wind

Yes. There are two major effects of wind on sound.

1. **Noise**: Wind is moving air and moving air is sound. It's mostly DC air movement so it's not audible per se, but it when the airflow hits objects it often creates wide band turbulences which can be quite loud. Particularly problematic is wind hitting the receivers i.e. a microphone or your ears. It can generate a lot of pick up noise. Wind screens are one way to deal with this.
2. **Waveform shaping**: Sound waves are moving with resect the fluid media (i.e. air). If the media moves as well, than the overall movement of the sound wave will be the sum of both motions and this deforms the wave shape. If the wind is relative constant you still get roughly spherical waves, but they are not concentric anymore, i.e. the center is moving with the wind. So your glass shatter would be significantly louder downwind then upwind.

Comment: Okay so there will be a directional element present to oppose it. Because the _medium_ of sound wave will be air. I neglected that fact in the theory, thanks for enlightenment!